# access cck fields in tpl file

Tags: theming, entities

I am working on one already created drupal site. In themes folder it has one tpl.php file, Where theme is done to display the content. Now it is as follows

**print $content**

And all the fields of cck are displayed properly. But I want to access every field like Title, Body etc. I have tried with **$content['title']**, But nothing is displayed.

Can anyone please tell me how to access different fields in my tpl file. I am using Drupal 6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it node.tpl.php ? What is the name of the .tpl.php file?

Comment: No it is not node.tpl.php. It it custom created tpl (modalframe-page.tpl.php).